# Get searched key word term from google

Tags: php, search

I just want to know if it is possible to get the keyword searched by the user in google when they come to our website from google.

I just need to know the technique and not the code, I can code, but do not know if this is technologically possible or not.

Thanks!
-D

Comment: You can use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) for this, but it's a big solution if all you want is to find the keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941469/is-it-possible-to-capture-search-term-from-google-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the HTTP_REFERER header sent by the browser using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. This contains the website (URL) the brower came from. Inside of this url you can also find the search term somewhere (if the visitor came from google).

This value might be empty because you can turn this feature off in your browser.

Comment: FYI: Google will **not** give you the keyword in the referer header. You can check this using any HTTP sniffer (such as Fiddler), and you'll see that the 'Referer' is set to `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ei=2Fd1UJD2IbDY0QXkhIHYBA&usg=AFQjCNERidL9Hb6OvGW93_Y6MRj3aTdMVA&sig2=8MZ93dEeR90RQPxbmfY5KA` when searching for `stackoverflow` (hence you only get the URL of your site, not their keyword).

Comment: @h2ooooooo (too many o's :P)

Any other way to do this? I know there is no value to the "q" variable :(

Comment: this not possible anymore due security changes (http://googleblog.blogspot.de/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html)

Comment: @DeeJay' As I mentioned in the OP, I *think* the only way is to use Google Analytics, but I *could* be wrong.

Comment: The referer is still available if the visitor wasn't logged into Google. So providing they weren't logged in then you can get the "q" variable of the referer.

Comment: referer url is available in the request header, but 'q' query string parameter is stripped off.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to get the referrer URL and then parse it to get the query string that was used to find your site. This [link](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/get-search-keywords-from-referrer/) gives some tips on how to achieve this easily.

Failing that, Google Analytics will tell you what search terms lead people to your site, but this is only really useful afterwords - you can't really use this to say "You found this site via *keyword*".

Comment: Please check before you post ... This wont work as the referer URL does not give you information about the "q" variable :(

Comment: It certainly used to up to a month or so ago. If it's not any more, then there's no way to see the referring query as a user comes to the page.

The solution I linked you to will still work for other search engines (Bing).

Answer (score 0):

You'll get 'q' parameter only from those queries which come from users not logged into Google services (gmail, docs, etc.) at the moment of the search.

Only way to get 'q' (keyword parameter) for all queries (as far as I am aware) is to implement https (ssl certificate) onto your site. However, your site would have to redirect all traffic from old http indexed pages (in google) to new https pages in order for this to work automatically.

Just be aware that by doing this you maybe stripping yourself of revenue, because secure sites (as of this moment) can't have Google Adsense implemented. (can, but it's not simple, for user to see, they would have to enable a prompt to show insecure content).

BTW. I know, it's a pain. Google is throwing more and more hurdles in our way and if this doesn't stop eventually people will start looking for a better service (business opportunity for rich).