# How to obtain Google search terms?

Tags: search

I have been tasked with finding a way to perform different actions, or display different content based on the search terms that someone used to find the site. I have seen other sites do this before (display my search terms to try to make the page look more relevant), but I don't know how this is done.

How can I fetch the search terms used to find the page?

Comment: your question is asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941469/is-it-possible-to-capture-search-term-from-google-search

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is usually done by inspecting the value of the HTTP_REFERRER.  You don't mention which language you're using, but you can obtain this in PHP with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`

Comment: I've heard that now most Google searches are over HTTPS which means the HTTP_REFERER does not contain the search terms. Is there any other way?