# Credibility of getting searched keyword in PHP

Tags: php, search, search-engine, keyword, yahoo

My Goal is to get exact keywords provided to a search engine by which a user has arrived to my webpage.
i found script to get these keywords from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941469/is-it-possible-to-capture-search-term-from-google-search/941515#941515).

```
$referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'google.' ) )
{
    parse_str( $referringPage['query'], $queryVars );
    echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
}
```

and also found following script from [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-keywords-search-engine-referer-url/).

```
function search_engine_query_string($url = false) {

    if(!$url) {
        $url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : false;
    }
    if($url == false) {
        return '';
    }

    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

    $search_engines = array(
        'bing' => 'q',
        'google' => 'q',
        'yahoo' => 'p'
    );

    preg_match('/(' . implode('|', array_keys($search_engines)) . ')\./', $parts['host'], $matches);

    return isset($matches[1]) && isset($query[$search_engines[$matches[1]]]) ? $query[$search_engines[$matches[1]]] : '';

}
```

My question is that what is the credibility of keywords got by these scripts, either these scripts give exact keywords from user provided to Search engine?

Comment: just install google analytics or any other stats software. And as far as im aware, google are not sending refer headers anymore, so you can forget about getting keywords from google unfortunatly

Comment: Google analytics doesn't give this information too. Google has stopped to give such keyword information. IF google doesn't give such information then any other state software cannot do that.

Comment: @user574632 i didn't find any software like this. can you tell me about any such software. Also if Google isn't providing this information then how any other software can provide information?

Comment: They can't, that's my point. Google analytics is your best bet.