# How to add user search queries in sitemap page?

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap

I need help, is it possible to auto add search queries from user and become a sitemap? It should every time user come from SE with keyword, and I want to make that keyword include in sitemap. I have the following code that include all post but not search keywords:

```
<ul id="toggle-view">
    <li>
        <h2>Posts</h2>
        <span>+</span>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset='.$debut);
                foreach($myposts as $post) :
                ?>
                <li class="sitemap"><?php the_time('d/m/y') ?>: 
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php //endwhile; ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Pages</h2>
        <span>+</span>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_type=page&offset='.$debut);
                foreach($myposts as $post) :
                ?>
                <li class="sitemap"><?php the_time('d/m/y') ?>:
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above code display all post and pages. Please teach me how to add the search queries. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to do this for SEO purposes - this might actually harm your rankings by listing duplicate content on multiple pages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941469/is-it-possible-to-capture-search-term-from-google-search

Comment: Thanks all. It not for SEO but for knowledge. I'll look at Andrew answer.