# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']? is only display google path in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this for Grabbing the referrer search engine keywords via which user came on our website. But all the time its only given me the 'https://www.google.co.in/'. So I want to know that is there any possibility to get search keyword or Google restrict it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941469/is-it-possible-to-capture-search-term-from-google-search/941515#941515

Comment: https://moz.com/blog/decoding-googles-referral-string-or-how-i-survived-secure-search

Comment: Referrers are never ever reliable. There aren't any reliable method to get pass this